# Has anyone added a ffdf object inside an R package?

Tags: r

After saving the object using "save.ffdf" It creates an .RData and a number of .ff files depending on the number of columns.

Do you put the .RData and the .ff files inside the data folder?

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you are asking and if possible expand upon this question with further details as to exactly what you hope to achieve.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to add the object. No problem. the ffdf (out of memory object can be created using the "ff" and the "ffbase" packages. When saving using the save.ffdf command it saves an .RData file and a number of ff files for each column the "ffdf" object has.  To put these files in a package, it has to be included in the "inst/extdata" folder of the package.  Once the package is installed, you would need to "load.ffdf" while pointing to the extdata folder, so R can find the out of memory objects once the package has been attached to the environment search path.  Thx